# Jquery Ajax error after loading intoa div

Tags: jquery, ajax

Suppose I have a page called index.php, it contains one div element name divContent which contain a button called "msg" and another button called "show".

When i load index.php two buttons show well. I have added jquery on my page. When click on my "msg" button it will show "successful" msg by

> alert("successful");

. Its work like when i click on show button (outside the divContent) it will load another page content to my divContent by ajax technique.

```
$('#msg').click(function(e) {
    alert("successful");
}); 
} //Whilst editing formatting - extra closing brace

$('#show').click(function(e) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "test.php",
        success: function(msg){
            $('#divContent').html(msg);
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});


test.php
--------
    <input type="button" id="msg" />
```

test.php contain a  button same as msg button present in index.php. My prob is when load index.php, click on the msg button it shows the successful msg but when click on show button it loads test.php's contains into divContent and click on msg button it does not shows "successful" message. What is the prob lem

Comment: is it showing any error in `Console`, in IE developer's tools?

Answer (score 0):

it's because you are binding a click to all of the existing #msg elements, it will not work on any element which doesn't exist at the time of the binding. so when you load new content, it doesn't have a click bound to it, you need to bind it again.

```
success: function(msg){
   $('#divContent').html(msg);
   $('#msg').click( .... );
}
```

OR, use the .on() method:

find an element which is an ancestor to both #msg buttons, and bind an event to it using .on

```
$('.parent').on('click', '#msg', function(){
   alert("whatever");
});
```

this will make sure that any #msg which is a child of .parent, regardless of when it was created, will have a click event.

source: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: thanks. but i wrote this for demo purpose bcoz purpose is same but code is other. i want to bind form element submit event on clicking on submit button. How to bind my form element with ON method.

Comment: You will need to bind your click only after the content is already showing up on the page. that means inside your success function, after `$('#divContent').html(msg);`

Comment: Submit will not work well with the ON method, because some older browsers don't bubble up the submit event through the DOM. so it is recommended to bind the click upon loading the element.

Comment: Ok.but i set parent to main div element and event click on form element on success function but not working.any help

Answer (score 0):

Your first click function has an extra closing brace.

```
$('#msg').click(function(e) {
    alert("successful");
}); 
} //<<Here
```